# SQL Server Application paths to include in server backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2017

I have an instance of SQL Server 2017 Standard installed on a physical server running Windows Server 2019. I'm currently working with our server administrator to configure the server backup, which he is using Symantec Backup Exec to complete. He is using the SQL Server agent to perform the SQL Server Database backups, but for the file backup I was wondering if there are any specific directories that it is best practice to include.

I'm under the impression that database and log files should be excluded from the file backup, but was wondering if there are any specific folders where SQL Server was installed to that should be included? I've tried looking this up in Microsoft's documentation and Googling it, but can only seem to find documentation regarding performing database backups.

Any advise would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For server backup on Windows the backup software will typically interact with the the [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vss/using-the-volume-shadow-copy-service) to generate a a point-in-time consistent view of each volume regardless of changing data or open files.

Then for server-level recovery, restore based on the volume snapshots to and then perform SQL Server database RESTORE using backups taken sometime later.

If you don't have the ability to protect whole volumes and open files, then the server backup is not going to be much use in any recovery scenario.